# Lucene problems searchinh hyphenated field

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I'm having some problems with Lucene that are driving me nuts. I have the following field:

```
doc.Add(new Field("cataloguenumber", i.CatalogueNumber.ToLower(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

Which will contain a catalogue number that looks something like this:

- DF-GH5
- DF-FJ4
- DF-DOG
- AC-DP
- AC-123
- AC-DOCO

i.e. two characters followed by a hyphen followed by 2-5 alphanumeric characters.

I'm trying to run a boolean query to allow users to search over the data:

```
// specify the search fields, lucene search in multiple fields
        string[] searchfields = new string[] { "cataloguenumber", "title", "author", "categories", "year", "length", "keyword", "description" };

        // Making a boolean query for searching and get the searched hits                
        BooleanQuery mainQuery = new BooleanQuery();
        QueryParser parser;

        //Add filter for main keyword
        parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, searchfields, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30));
        parser.AllowLeadingWildcard = true;
        mainQuery.Add(parser.Parse(GetMainSearchQueryString(SearchPhrase)), Occur.MUST);
```

The system is working fine for all fields EXCEPT cataloguenumber which for whatever reason is not working at all.

Ideally we would like to be able to search by full or partial cataloguenumber so for example "DF-" should return all items prefixed DF

Does anyone know how I can make this work?

Thanks very much in advance

Olly

Comment: It's worth adding that I know this field is being indexed (in some form) because I've opened the _mcd.cfs file and I can see some catalogue numbers in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common source of problems is to use different analyzers on index-time and query-time. You should be able to get good results by using a `StandardAnalyzer` - it treats the text `DF-GH5` as a single token so you will be able to search using fx `df-gh5` or `df-*` but make sure to use it for the `IndexWriter` and the `QueryParser`.

Here is a simple example which builds an in-memory index with a single document, and tries to query the index by `cataloguenumber`.

```
public static void Test()
{
    // Use an in-memory index.
    RAMDirectory indexDirectory = new RAMDirectory();

    // Make sure to use the same analyzer for indexing 
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);

    // Add single document to the index.
    using (IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(indexDirectory, analyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED))
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        document.Add(new Field("content", "This is just some text", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        document.Add(new Field("cataloguenumber", "DF-GH5", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

        writer.AddDocument(document);
    }

    var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(
        Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30,
        new[] { "cataloguenumber", "content" },
        analyzer);

    var searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexDirectory);

    DoSearch("df-gh5", parser, searcher);
    DoSearch("df-*", parser, searcher);
}

private static void DoSearch(string queryString, MultiFieldQueryParser parser, IndexSearcher searcher)
{
    var query = parser.Parse(queryString);

    TopDocs docs = searcher.Search(query, 10);

    foreach (ScoreDoc scoreDoc in docs.ScoreDocs)
    {
        Document searchHit = searcher.Doc(scoreDoc.Doc);
        string cataloguenumber = searchHit.GetValues("cataloguenumber").FirstOrDefault();
        string content = searchHit.GetValues("content").FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine($"Found object: {cataloguenumber} {content}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Working like a charm!! Thank you so much!